# How can I get my Windows CE Embedded device to recognize a file share?

Tags: c#, networking, embedded, windows-ce, share

I'm trying to access a file share on the network on my embedded windows CE Device.  The device is running an ARM4VI processor with Windows CE 6.0.  I have set up the file share properly since I can access it from other windows computers on the network.  I have tried configuring a network share on multiple computers.  I'm trying to access a SQLite database over the network.  I'm using SQLite's Interop ADO.NET wrapper that's compatible with .NET CF 2.0 and 3.5.  I have verified that this isn't the issue  I've been browsing forums for 3 days  trying to figure out how I can talk to that device or if it is even possible.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Matt - did you ever find a solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

How do you share your folder on the Desktop?
Try to not use simple file sharing. Share it manually with read access (at least) to all.